# jQuery UI sortable - dynamically change content on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two blocks, one is "draggable only" and the other is "droppable only".

Inside the first one I have some images which I can drag and drop them into the second one.

After I drop the image from the first block into the second one I want to replace the dropped image with a bigger image.

I'm thinking to use `replaceWith()` method but the problem is that is replacing also the parent element.

For example, I have this in the "draggable only":

```
<li class="draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="header-1">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
</li>
```

and this in the "droppable only" after the element is dragged from the "droppable only":

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
```

As you noticed the `replaceWith()` is replacing the parent element also and I don't want this.

**Also I need way to dinamically add an image based on what item was dragged.**

Right now, is like this :

```
$('.testing').replaceWith('<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">');
```

This will replace every item with the same image and I don't want this.Every item should have it's own image.

This is the JS code for the "draggable only":

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
     connectToSortable: '.sortableList',
     cursor: 'pointer',
     helper: 'clone',
     revert: 'invalid',
     start: function (event, ui) {
         $(this).addClass('testing');
     }
 });
```

and this is fro the "droppable only":

```
$(".sortableList").sortable({
     receive: function (event, ui) {
         //alert('It works');
         $('.testing').replaceWith('<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">');
     }
 });
```

Here's a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/dajec/1) ( HOVER OVER "HEADERS" AND DRAG AND DROP THE IMAGE OVER THE CONTAINER IN THE RIGHT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put addClass("testing") inside function of recieve under sortable method instead of inside start of draggable method, it should work

```
$(".sortableList").sortable({
     receive: function (event, ui) {
         //alert('It works');
           $(this).addClass('testing');
         $('.testing').replaceWith('<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">');
     }
 });



 $(".draggable").draggable({
     connectToSortable: '.sortableList',
     cursor: 'pointer',
     helper: 'clone',
     revert: 'invalid',
     start: function (event, ui) {
       //Not here
     }
 });
```

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vuwinoca/1)

[**Check the Updated Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chakravarthysm/2ac8nrxf/)

Comment: Yes, this seems to work, but how about adding an specific image for each element dragged and dropped ?

Comment: Check this http://jsbin.com/vuwinoca/4, is this is you want?, if so use $("ul.sortableList").each(function(){
  $(this).sortable({
     receive: function (event, ui) {
         //alert('It works');
$(this).addClass('testing');         $('.testing').replaceWith('<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">');
     }
 });
});  and use a dynamic variable inside replaceWith() whose value is the img src which changes dynamically

Comment: I think you didn't understood exactly what I said. For example if the user drags the first image from "Headers" to replace the dropped image with a big image and if he drags the second image to replace it with another big image, not the same as the first one.

Comment: If you still don't understand exactly, I will accept this answer and post another question with more details about what I want to do.

Comment: Sorry bro, I'm not getting you properly